# How am I supposed to distribute the file licensed under this license?

Tags: licensing

I'm making a game in that requires the CSFML libraries. I've downloaded the libraries from: http://dsfml.com/downloads.html

I can't understand these things, the license doesn't explain much:

1. I only want to distribute the files in the lib folder, can I? Not the whole package.
2. If I can, where do I put the license.txt? Given that the files will be put in the `/lib` directory in the FileSystem.

P.S: I downloaded the 32 bit Linux package from that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSFML library is [licensed under](https://github.com/Jebbs/DSFML/blob/master/License.txt) the [ZLIB license](https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/zlib/#license-text)

When redistributing binaries, the zlib requirements are ... minimal. In fact there are no requirements in that case beside not claiming that I wrote this library.

Therefore I do not need to do anything special and in particular I do not need to include the license text in a binary-only redistribution. The zlib license has no such requirement for binaries.

However, the right thing do is to meet also the suggested requirements:

> If you use this software in a product, an acknowledgement in the product documentation would be appreciated but is not required.

Therefore I would include in my product documentation and/or credits page some acknowledgement for that library. Since I want to do the right thing and I may also include several other open source libraries in my product, I would also include the [copyright notice and license text[1](https://github.com/Jebbs/DSFML/blob/master/License.txt) for good measure even if this not strictly required here: this way I would just treat this as the other libraries and include all the license and notice texts.

Answer (score 2):

Distributing only the files in the `lib/` folder is technically to "alter it". Thus, you should include the License.txt file in the `lib/` folder as well, but including a first line explaining it was altered. Example:

> This folder contains part of the DSFML library. This library is licensed as such: